# Retrieve data from a callback thats in a promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird, es6-promise

I have  the following piece of code right now:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const readFile = Promise.promisify(fs.readFile);
recordPerfMetrics: function(url) {

    var self = this;
    var perf, loadTime, domInteractive, firstPaint;
    var perfData = {};       
    readFile('urls.txt', 'UTF-8').then(function (urls, err) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }

        var urls = urls.split("\n");
        urls.shift();

        urls.forEach(function(url) {     
            console.log(url);   
            self.getStats(url).then(function(data) { 
                data = data[0];
                loadTime = (data.loadEventEnd - data.navigationStart)/1000 + ' sec';
                firstPaint = data.firstPaint;
                domInteractive = (data.domInteractive - data.navigationStart)/1000 + ' sec';

                perfData = {
                    'URL' : url,
                    'firstPaint' : firstPaint,
                    'loadTime' : loadTime,
                    'domInteractive' : domInteractive
                };
                console.log(perfData);
            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        });      

        // console.log(colors.magenta("Starting to record performance metrics for " + url));
        // this.storePerfMetrics();                       
    });    
},

getStats: function(url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        console.log("Getting data for url: ",url);
        browserPerf(url, function(error, data) {
            console.log("inside browserPerf", url);
            if (!error) {
                resolve(data);
              } else {
                reject(error);
            }
        }, {
            selenium: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
            browsers: ['chrome']
        });
    });
},
```

This is basically reading urls from a file and then calling a function browserPerf whose data being returned is in a callback function.

The `console.log("Getting data for url: ",url);` is in the same order as the urls that are stored in the file,

but the `console.log("inside browserPerf", url);` is not conjunction as the same and as expected.

I expect the order of the urls to be:

```
console.log(url);   
console.log("Getting data for url: ",url);
console.log("inside browserPerf", url);
```

But for reason only the first two are executed in order but the third one is fired randomly after all are being read.
Any idea what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: Your `.forEach()` loop runs synchronously.  The async operations inside it are all started at once and will finish whenever with no regard for the `.forEach()` loop.  If you want to coordinate when multiple promises are done, you either sequence them to run one after the other or you use `Promise.all()` to get notified when they are all done.  There are hundreds of others questions/answers that explain how to do either one of those options.

Comment: Also, since you are using Bluebird, try replace `.forEach()`, with Bluebird's map function, it also has a concurrency option that's nice.

Comment: Are you trying to sequence your URLs one after the other or get stats on all of them in parallel and then know when they are all ready?

Comment: @jfriend00: i am trying to seq the urls once they are ready and gets the stats after one is ready, then the next one, then the next and so on.. so if we have: www.abc.com,www.xyz.com,www.aaa.com, I want the stats for abc,xyz and then aaa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Bluebird, you can replace your `.forEach()` loop with `Promise.mapSeries()` and it will sequentially walk through your array waiting for each async operation to finish before doing the next one.  The result will be a promise who's resolved value is an array of results.  You also should stop declaring local variables in a higher scope when you have async operations involved.  Declare them in the nearest scope practical which, in this case is the scope in which they are used.

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const readFile = Promise.promisify(fs.readFile);

recordPerfMetrics: function() {

    var self = this;
    return readFile('urls.txt', 'UTF-8').then(function (urls) {
        var urls = urls.split("\n");
        urls.shift();

        return Promise.mapSeries(urls, function(url) {     
            console.log(url);   
            return self.getStats(url).then(function(data) { 
                data = data[0];
                let loadTime = (data.loadEventEnd - data.navigationStart)/1000 + ' sec';
                let firstPaint = data.firstPaint;
                let domInteractive = (data.domInteractive - data.navigationStart)/1000 + ' sec';

                let perfData = {
                    'URL' : url,
                    'firstPaint' : firstPaint,
                    'loadTime' : loadTime,
                    'domInteractive' : domInteractive
                };
                console.log(perfData);
                return perfData;
            }).catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
                throw error;    // keep the promise rejected
            });
        });      

        // console.log(colors.magenta("Starting to record performance metrics for " + url));
        // this.storePerfMetrics();                       
    });    
},

getStats: function(url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        console.log("Getting data for url: ",url);
        browserPerf(url, function(error, data) {
            console.log("inside browserPerf", url);
            if (!error) {
                resolve(data);
              } else {
                reject(error);
            }
        }, {
            selenium: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
            browsers: ['chrome']
        });
    });
},
```

You would use this like this:

```
obj.recordPerfMetrics().then(function(results) {
    // process results array here (array of perfData objects)
}).catch(function(err) {
    // error here
});
```

Summary of changes:

1. Return promise from recordPefMetrics so caller can get data
2. Use `Promise.mapSeries()` instead of `.forEach()` for sequential async operations.
3. Return promise from `Promise.mapSeries()` so it is chained with prior promise.
4. Move variable declarations into local scope so there is no change of different async operations stomping on shared variables.
5. Rethrow `.catch()` error after logging so the reject propagates
6. `return perfData` so it becomes the resolved value and is available in results array.

Comment: @jp310 - Don't miss the edits I just did to fix a few more things.